# monitors & notify & notify all in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor

I'm doing an online quiz related to monitors. Those are the 4 true or false questions and my answers. If my answers are wrong, can you please explain why?

1. Starvation will definitely not occur when using monitors in Java if notifyAll() is used **T**
2. Only objects that are declared to extend thread or implement runnable have a monitor lock in Java **F**

Comment: Strange quiz. Java doesn't really have monitors in the Brich-Hansen sense. When he saw Java he commented 'clearly I have laboured in vain'.

Comment: Do you have reason to think they're wrong?

Comment: @shmosel I don't, just want to make sure that they are correct.

Comment: @EJP exactly, I have programmed in Java for 2 years and never heard of monitors :/

Comment: I think the monitor terminology is derived from the jvm monitorenter/monitorexit instructions

Comment: @SamJackson I have programmed in Java for 20+ years and ditto.

Comment: What? You can't be serious.

Comment: @schmosel I'm perfectly serious. There are no monitors in Java. What there is is a mad wait/notify system borrowed from the UNIX kernel, and rather inflexible scope-oriented synchronization primitives.

Answer (score 1):

> Starvation will definitely not occur when using monitors in Java if notifyAll() is used.   **F**

If a thread is not granted CPU time because other threads grab it all, it is called "starvation". [Check here for
   more.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/starvation-and-fairness.html)

- When using `notifyAll()`, JVM awakens all threads and then all
  threads race for the lock on this object. Now, CPU scheduler selects
  a thread which acquires lock on this object. This means using
  `notifyAll()` can not avoid starvation since some threads may always lose the contention.
- Also, Threads are blocked indefinately waiting to enter a
  synchronized block, because other threads are constantly allowed
  access before it. Starvation will also occur.

> Only objects that are declared to extend thread or implement runnable
>   have a monitor lock in Java. **F**

Every class roots from `java.lang.Object` has monitor lock. [Check here for more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362303/whats-a-monitor-in-java)