# What's a good, efficient way to implement run()?

Tags: java, multithreading

Should it just contain a loop like

```
while (true) { ... }
```

I find it not so efficient as it consumes the CPU so much. I would like my thread to keep on waiting for something but what's the best way to make it wait without consuming so much CPU?

Comment: If you want to wait, use `wait()`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do this efficiently using `Object.wait` and `Object.notify` (see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)), or using various higher level Java concurrency classes such as blocking queues, latches, futures, semaphores or barriers.

===================================================

You are correct that repeatedly testing the condition is a really bad idea; e.g.

```
    while (!condition) {
        // really bad idea ... burns CPU cycles.
    }
```

The following is an improvement, but can still be problematic:

```
    while (!condition) {
        Thread.sleep(...);  // bad idea
    }
```

The problem is that if you set the sleep interval short, the loop gets expensive.  But if you set it longer (e.g. a second or so), then the thread can take up to that amount of time to respond to the condition becoming true.  The net result can be reduced throughput and / or sluggish user interfaces.

Sometimes the `loop{test; sleep}` approach is the best available option, unfortunately, but if you can avoid it, you should.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `while(true) {}`. If you are waiting for some event, do `wait()-notify()` mechanism. Otherwise, use `sleep(nsecs)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than wait for something, it sounds like you could use the [Observer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) pattern.  The Observer maintains a list of it's dependents, called Observables, and notifies them of any changes, usually by calling one of the Observer methods.

Here's how you would [code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/AsimpledemoofObservableandObserver.htm) an Observer class and an Observable class.

```
/** The Observer normally maintains a view on the data */
class MyView implements Observer {
    /** For now, we just print the fact that we got notified. */
    public void update(Observable obs, Object x) {
        System.out.println("update(" + obs + "," + x + ");");
    }
}

/** The Observable normally maintains the data */
class MyModel extends Observable {
    public void changeSomething() {
       // Notify observers of change
       setChanged();
       notifyObservers();
    }
}
```