# Difference between threads states

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, thread-sleep, thread-synchronization

In java a thread can be stopped in two ways either by **user** (by calling sleep or wait) or by a **synchronized block**.
The thread stops working or is blocked (waiting for a lock to be released by some other thread) when it tries to enter the synchronized block(if some other thread has acquired the same lock).

So I wanted to know if there is any difference in the states of the threads (by state I mean thread variables, context etc) blocked by synchronized block and the user methods like sleep in java.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If there is a meaningful difference depends on that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep

Comment: @Thilo: Actually I was reading this article
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-threads/section5.html and thought that a sleeping thread can be re-invoked by an interrupt or by completing the sleep time.
So was just curious about if there is any difference in these approaches or are just same internally.

Comment: So the question is if a thread that blocks on a monitor (synchronized keyword) can be interrupted?

Comment: @Thilo: Actually the question that you suggested also came in my mind, but I think it can restrict some of the information. I mean if I know the state of the thread I can use that information instead of just interrupting it.

Answer (score 0):

**-** When a thread is doing `IO` operations or it executing a `sychronized` block, then it **canNot be interrupted.**

**-** When a `thread` tries to access a `synchronized` block of an **object** whose `key` is already being taken by some other thread, then this thread trying to access the synchronized block will enter the `block` state.