# How to wake up a thread before time is up

Tags: java

i am working on a Java application and i reach a point where i want to pause the execution for few seconds ( chosen by the user ) and resume it latter ..and here is a simple code :

```
Public Class myApp
{
    static public main()
    { 
       int seconds=10;
       // do couple of things 
       try {
                   Thread.sleep(10*1000);
               } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                   Logger.getLogger(myApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,    null,      ex);
               }
    }
```

i want now to give the user a chance by clicking on a button to resume the execution even before the time is up .
is this possible using "Thread.sleep()" ? or there is another way to pause App and resume  it ?

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: You will need to interrupt the thread, but you may also want to reset the interrupted flag by calling [`Thread#interrupted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted())

Comment: @shazin i am using Java 6

Comment: @MadProgrammer  if i  interrupt the thread, will make it resume even if the Thread is sleeping ?

Comment: You need to interrupt the "sleeping" thread.  But yes, that's why you need to catch `InterruptedException`, so you know when the thread was woken prematurely...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  uh i see ...Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); is that how do i interrupt  the main Thread ?

Comment: The problem with what you just said is, `Thread.currentThread` is asleep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CountDownLatch`

```
Public Class myApp
{
    static CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    static public main()
    {        
       try {
            countDownLatch.await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Logging
       }
    }
}
```

and you can call `countDownLatch.countDown()` method from the resume button on click

Comment: You can do this with sleep as well, as wait/notify and many other options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wait` in place of `sleep` to pause the thread execution. Then you can use `notify` or `notifyAll` to wake up the waiting thread.

Comment: How can i use wait with Main() ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you tell me how could i do it with "main()" ? i mean how to make it wait for some seconds ... i m still new with those notions ..thank you

Comment: @user2746896 [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep) may give you an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use interrupt to cancel the sleep, here are more info:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html