# Java Threads: Using sleep and interrupt rather than wait and notifyAll

Tags: java, multithreading

**Scenario** - Trying to achieve the result with `sleep()` and `interrupt()`; which 
would have been otherwise done by `wait()` and `notifyAll()`

**Question -** I know this way is not preferred. Can you guys please let me know what is wrong in doing like this in this below
scenario.

*One reason is* `notifyAll()` notify all threads looking for the lock on that object. But with `interrupt()` 
we have the invoke interrupt on each waiting thread explicitly.

*Other reason is* that a different thread cannot change the object state. Here the initial thread itself make
`food=true` on catching an `InterruptedException`. But what is wrong with that?

```
/**
 * Objective of this program:
 * 
 * I was thinking, why can't we achieve the guarded block with Sleep and Interrupt,
 * why only with wait and notify..
 * 
 * Wait releases lock; while Sleep does not . But both suspend the execution. 
 * So if you are synchronizing on the object, then we cannot have the second thread
 * to modify the object state due the lock on the object, and the second thread cannot acquire it.
 * 
 * So I did a explicit interrupt on the first thread.
 * 
 */
/**
 * 
 * One person ask if he has something to eat polling the "food" variable.
 * Another person updates the shared variable food.
 * 
 * food = true means the first person can start eating. food = false means he
 * has to wait and poll the value until food is available(food = true). This is
 * not a producer-consumer problem.
 * 
 */

public class _17GuardedBlockWithSleep_Interrupt_Badcase {

    static class Person {

        volatile boolean food;

        public boolean isFood() {
            return food;
        }

        public void setFood(boolean food) {
            this.food = food;
        }

        String name;

        Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        /*
         * Sloppy/Bad way of implementation making it pause execution until it
         * gets interrupted. An interruption alone does not mean food is
         * available. May be interrupt was called by someone else who does not
         * provide food. So check the condition too.
         * 
         * Through sleep(), the execution is paused. CPU is free to take other
         * tasks, The lock on object is NOT released so other threads CANNOT
         * acquire the lock on the object.
         */

        // Guarded Block
        public synchronized void eatFood() {
            while (!isFood()) {
                // food is currently unavailable. I'm waiting..
                try {
                    /**
                     * Ideally we do wait() and notifyAll() in such a scenario. I am
                     * trying with Sleep and Interrupt.
                     */
                    Thread.sleep(1000000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    this.setFood(true);// it's not some other thread that provide food. it's itself!
                    System.out.println("eatFood() caught InterruptedException");
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // if control comes here, then it means food is available
            System.out.println("got the food.. yummyy..thanks!");
        }

        public synchronized void provideFood(Thread t) {
            this.setFood(true); // this refers to current object. In this case, the
                                        // 'kuttappan' object
            // interrupt the first thread
            t.interrupt();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Person kuttappan = new Person("Kuttappan");

        Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /*
                 * if kuttappan is not already defined as final, you get an error
                 * "Cannot refer to a non-final variable kuttappan inside an inner class defined in a different method"
                 */
                kuttappan.eatFood();
                /*
                 * thread will try to acquire the lock on 'kuttappan' object when it
                 * invokes the synchronized method.
                 */
            }
        };
        final Thread t = new Thread(runnable1, "thread1");
        t.start();

        // someone is needed to make the food available for kuttappan.

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000); // 5 seconds
                    t.interrupt(); // MY IMPORTANT LINE
                    // kuttappan.provideFood(t);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

/**
 * OUTPUT:
 * 
 * Observe the line commented as "MY IMPORTANT LINE"
 * 
 * If you do 'kuttappan.provideFood(t);' then the program Keeps on running. no
 * output, because
 * 
 * The second thread cannot get into provideFood() of kuttappan object because
 * the first thread has not released the lock on the object!
 * 
 * But if you do t.interrupt(); the thread is interrupted and the program
 * behaves as expected.
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here: [Difference between wait() and sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep)

"Sleeping a `Thread` does *not* release the locks it holds, while waiting releases the lock on the object that `wait()` is called on."

So in your case it appears that if there is no food available it's impossible for another thread to go in and make food available.

<strike>It also appears that even if you call `t.interrupt()`, the first thread will just see that there isn't any food, so it'll sleep again. I could very well be interpreting this incorrectly though...</strike> working on this...

Never mind, I misread part of your code. I think part of the problem is that you rely on the original thread itself to do the work that the second thread should have done. So really you're not doing much better than having a single thread add food then consume it...

Comment: "So in your case it appears that if there is no food available it's impossible for another thread to go in and make food available" - Yes that is correct. That's what I mentioned in my code comments at the end "OUTPUT" section. wait() release the lock, where sleep() does not. But I bypass that limitation by making food available on catching the interruption.

Comment: Yep, updated. I think that in this case it's sort of just abuse of concurrency, because effectively all you're doing is telling the original thread to sleep for some shorter time, add food, then eat food.

Comment: Yes, now you interpreted it correctly. Thanks for your time on reading it +1. You are right. I am making the first thread to look for food availability, and when someone gives a notification [interruption], it itself makes the food available and consumes it.

Comment: I guess this isn't wrong in terms of functionality... My guess is that it's the poor use of exceptions and increased complexity that make programmers prefer `wait()` and `notifyAll()`. Also, although this doesn't apply to your example, using this idea probably wouldn't scale too well if you have many providers.

Comment: If I scale this example to typical scenario of multiple producers and only one consumer, then the only limitation is that the producers must have access to the consumer thread reference inorder to call consumerthread.interrupt(); . But If I scale this example to multiple consumers and multiple producers who all work on same chores, then this becomes worse and least efficient. We should use wait and notifyAll(). Can you validate this statement?

Comment: If you have too many producers you'll end up with lots of `InterruptedExceptions`, but because you aren't interacting with the object directly I don't think that'd be too horrible. I'm not even sure if multiple consumers for the same object is possible because they would all need to lock that same object, right? Unless you have multiple consumers each locking different objects, in which case the only issue is keeping track of all the `Thread` references. In any case, `wait()` and `notifyAll()` are probably simpler solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I got enough points here. I'll wrap this up. Finally to your specific statement.. Yes multiple consumers for the same object is not possible as they cannot acquire lock. The comments as such is explanatory enough.

Answer (score 1):

Its a poor choice because you are counting on one thread catching an interrupted exception every time.  Exceptions are a high overhead mechanism for IPC.  There may be more reasons but this is enough to get it yanked out of production code.

Comment: I will not write that code even in development code, cannot even think of production! insane!. I wrote that sample class to understand the reasons why such a practice is strongly discouraged. I knew some of the reasons and limitations. I like to know more.Your point is one among them. Thank you for that, +1.

Comment: Thank you, that was more valid point - "catching an interrupted exception every time. Exceptions are a high overhead mechanism for IPC"

Answer (score 1):

I think in your scenario producer thread should always have reference to consumer thread in order to `interrupt()` it and give it possibility to process "event".

If you use `wait()`/`notify()` you do not need threads to know each other, all you need is a synchronization point - object that you wait/notify on. Also you can share this object with as many threads as you want. So at the end producer thread does not care who exactly waits for the resource, it only needs to send signal that resource is available.

Comment: it only needs to send signal that resource is available.producer need to always have the "consumer thread reference" in this scenario. " it only needs to send signal that resource is available." Well Said Yes, I too thought of it as one of the limitations. and in many cases, it is too much a limitation. Thanks, +1