# Having Threads wait for one another.

Tags: java, multithreading

So I currently have this code

```
class PrintDemo {
public void printCount(){
try {
     for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Counter   ---   "  + i );
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Thread  interrupted.");
   } 
 }

 }

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
private Thread t;
private String threadName;
PrintDemo  PD;

ThreadDemo( String name,  PrintDemo pd){
    threadName = name;
     PD = pd;
}
public void run() {
  synchronized(PD) {
     PD.printCount();
  }
  System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
}

public void start ()
{
   System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
  if (t == null)
  {
     t = new Thread (this, threadName);
     t.start ();
  }
 }

}

public class TestThread {
public static void main(String args[]) {

  PrintDemo PD = new PrintDemo();

  ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 1 ", PD );
  ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 2 ", PD );

  T1.start();
  T2.start();

  // wait for threads to end
  try {
     T1.join();
     T2.join();
  } catch( Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Interrupted");
  }
```

And it Prints out the following output:

```
Starting Thread - 1
Starting Thread - 2
Counter   ---   5
Counter   ---   4
Counter   ---   3
Counter   ---   2
Counter   ---   1
Thread Thread - 1  exiting.
Counter   ---   5
Counter   ---   4
Counter   ---   3
Counter   ---   2
Counter   ---   1
Thread Thread - 2  exiting.
```

Is there any way I can have Thread 1 decrease by one and then thread 2 by one until both are at 1, instead of having just thread 1 decrease to 1 and then thread 2 decrease to 1.

Comment: Yes.. Remove the join method. Maybe I do t understand your question well enough but have you tried taking the join out?

Comment: use `wait` and `notify`

Comment: where exactly would I add the wait and notify?

Comment: see if this helps ur qn - Use wait & notify/notifyAll; and not sleep & interrupt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436454/java-threads-using-sleep-and-interrupt-rather-than-wait-and-notifyall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are sharing same object of `PrintDemo` class in both threads that you can use as lock (monitor).

sample code:

```
class PrintDemo {
    public void printCount() {
        try {
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    this.notify();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Counter   ---   " + i);
                synchronized (this) {
                    this.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Thread  interrupted.");
        }
    }
}

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;
    PrintDemo PD;

    ThreadDemo(String name, PrintDemo pd) {
        threadName = name;
        PD = pd;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (PD) {
            PD.printCount();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");

        synchronized (PD) {
            PD.notify(); // notify the last waited thread.
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Starting Thread - 1 
Starting Thread - 2 
Thread - 1  Counter   ---   5
Thread - 2  Counter   ---   5
Thread - 1  Counter   ---   4
Thread - 2  Counter   ---   4
Thread - 1  Counter   ---   3
Thread - 2  Counter   ---   3
Thread - 1  Counter   ---   2
Thread - 2  Counter   ---   2
Thread - 1  Counter   ---   1
Thread - 2  Counter   ---   1
Thread Thread - 1  exiting.
Thread Thread - 2  exiting.
```

Visual representation:

[image]

[Read more...](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/wait_notify_how_to.shtml)