# Synchronized blocks don't work when using member of unrelated class as lock object?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Pretty much all resources I've found on synchronized blocks use *this* or a member of the class as a lock object. I'm interested in finding out why I can't get synchronized blocks to work when the lock object is a (static) member of another class. Here's my code to illustrate the problem:

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new FirstThread();
        Thread thread2 = new SecondThread();
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        }
    }

class FirstThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (Lock.lock) {
            System.out.println("First thread entered block");
            try {
                Lock.lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("First thread exited block");
    }
}

class SecondThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); //just making sure second thread enters synch block after first thread
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (Lock.lock) {
            System.out.println("Second thread entered block");
            Lock.lock.notifyAll();
        }
        System.out.println("Second thread exited block");
    }
}

class Lock {
    public static Object lock = new Object();
}
```

My understanding is that the second thread should not be able to enter the synchronized block until the first thread exits, since they are synchronized on the same object. Thus I was expecting the program to hang (deadlock?) after "First thread entered block", since the second thread can't enter the block and the first thread will be stuck waiting for a notification. But instead I got the following output:

```
First thread entered block

Second thread entered block

Second thread exited block

First thread exited block
```

Clearly the second thread enters the synchronized block before the first thread has left it's block. Can someone explain what I'm missing? 
I thought the purpose of synchronized blocks was to prevent exactly this. Is it because the lock object is a member of another class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first thread Lock.lock.wait() relinquish the lock on the synchronized object so other thread can enter the critical path and wake up the waiters.

note that sleep(), instead, does not.

[Difference between wait() and sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep)

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [javadoc of `Object.wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29):

> The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method.

If that was not the case, waiting would systematically cause a deadlock, since no thread would ever be able to enter the synchronized section  needed to call `notify()` or `notifyAll()`, making wait and notify completely useless.

Comment: Yes I realized this after some additional googling for an unrelated question. My face is quite red right now.

Answer (score 1):

When you call lock.[wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) you "release ownership of this monitor". This allows thread 2 to enter the synchronized block.