# J2ME - How to make a thread return a value and after that thread is finished, use the return value in other operations?

Tags: multithreading, java-me

I got some questions regarding the use of threads, specially when you have to wait for a thread to be finished so you can perform other operations.

In my app, I use threads for operations such as http connections or when I read from or write to a RecordStore.

For example in the following class that I use to initialize my thread, I retrieve some customers from a webservice using the method called **HttpQueryCustomers**.

```
    public class thrLoadCustomers implements Runnable {

    private RMSCustomer mRMSCustomer;    
    private String mUrl;

    public thrLoadCustomers(RMSCustomer rmsCust, String url) {        
        mRMSCustomer = rmsCust;        
        mUrl = url;
    }

    public void run() {
        String jsonResultados = "";
        try {
            jsonResultados = HttpQueryCustomers();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //How to show a message from here??
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
             //How to show a message here??
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
             //How to show a message from here??
        }
        if (!jsonResultados.equals("")) {
            try {
                mRMSCustomer.save(jsonResultados);
            } catch (RecordStoreException ex) {
               //How to show a message from here???
            }
        }

    }

    public String HttpQueryCustomers() throws IOException,SecurityException,NullPointerException {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        HttpConnection hc = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        System.out.println(mUrl);
        try {
            hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(mUrl);

            if (hc.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                is = hc.openInputStream();
                int ch;
                while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuffer.append((char) ch);
                }
            }

        } finally {
            is.close();
            hc.close();
        }
        String jsonData = stringBuffer.toString();
        return jsonData.toString();
    }
}
```

Notice in the above class that I pass a parameter called **rmsCust** of the type **RMSCustomer**

**RMSCustomer** is a class that I use to handle all the operations related to RMS:

```
public class RMSCustomer {

    private String mRecordStoreName;
    private Customer[] mCustomerList;

    public RMSCustomer(String recordStoreName) {
        mRecordStoreName = recordStoreName;
    }

    public Customer[] getCustomers() {
        return mCustomerList;
    }

    public Customer get(int index) {
        return mCustomerList[index];
    }  

    public void save(String data) throws RecordStoreException,JSONException,NullPointerException {
        RecordStore rs = null;
        int idNuevoRegistro;
        String stringJSON;
        try {
            rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore(mRecordStoreName, true);

            JSONArray js = new JSONArray(data); 
            //Set the size of the array
            mCustomerList = new Customer[js.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsObj = js.getJSONObject(i);
                stringJSON = jsObj.toString();                   
                idNuevoRegistro = addRecord(stringJSON, rs); 
                //Add a new Customer to the array
                mCustomerList[i] = initializeCustomer(stringJSON, idNuevoRegistro);
            }


        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.closeRecordStore();
            }
        }
    }

    public int addRecord(String stringJSON, RecordStore rs) throws JSONException,RecordStoreException {                    
        byte[] raw = stringJSON.getBytes();
        int idNuevoRegistro = rs.addRecord(raw, 0, raw.length);
        return idNuevoRegistro;             
    }   

    public Customer initializeCustomer(String stringJSON, int idRecord) throws JSONException {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(stringJSON);
        // Set Customer properties 
        //...
        return c;
    }


}
```

This class is used to show a list of customer and ,as you can see, it extends the **List** class and receives an array of Customers as a parameter.

```
public class ListCustomers extends List {

    private final Customer[] mData;

    public static ListCustomers create(Customer[] data) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] == null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        String[] names = new String[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            names[j] = data[j].name;
        }
        return new ListCustomers(names, data);
    }

    protected ListCustomers(String names[], Customer[] data) {
        super("List of Customer", IMPLICIT, names, null);
        mData = data;
    }
    public Customer getSelectedObject() {
        return mData[this.getSelectedIndex()];
    }
}
```

Finally **this is how I call the thread from the MIDlet** (using all the 3 previous classes) when I want to show a List of Customers:

```
private void showCustomerList(String url) {
        showWaitForm();
        if (scrCustomerList == null) {            
            rmsCustomers = new RMSCustomer("rmsCustomers");          

            thrLoadCustomers load = new thrLoadCustomers(rmsCustomers, url);
            Thread t = new Thread(load);
            t.start();
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
            scrCustomerList = ListCustomers.create(rmsCustomers.getCustomers());
            scrCustomerList.addCommand(cmdSelect);
            scrCustomerList.addCommand(cmdBack);
            scrCustomerList.setCommandListener(this);
        }
        mDisplay.setCurrent(scrCustomerList);
    }
```

Now here's the problems I have  :

1. The `showWaitForm()` doesn't work (it sets a form with a Gauge as the
   Current form)
2. I don't know how to show all the exceptions that might be thrown from
   within the **thrLoadCustomers** class.
3. I don't know whether using `t.join()` is the best choice
4. The last question is about something the [book I'm reading](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321463420)  says :

> Threads, in particular, can be a scarce commodity. The MSA
>   specification requires that an application must be allowed to create
>   **ten threads**. Just because you can doesn’t mean you should. In general,
>   try to use the fewest resources possible so that your application will
>   run as smoothly as possible

This is the first time a use threads, and in my app I might have up to 10 threads (classes). However, I will only execute once thread at the time, will I be going against what the previous quotation says??

I hope I'm not asking too many questions. Thank you very much for your help.

P.D Much of the code I posted here wouldn't have been possible with the help of [Gregor Ophey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938574/gregor-ophey)

Comment: Does J2ME have Future and Callable? I'd either backport those or reimplement those concepts.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann These classes are not available, and I'd advise against trying to code a DIY replacement unless you are quite experienced in concurrent programming.

Comment: @MisterSmith The source for these classes is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question #1 is about a different problem not related to threading, and for which very little code is shown. I'd suggest you to post a new dedicated question with proper explanation of the issue.

Questions #2 and #3: You could define a wrapper class like this:

```
    public class WSResult {
        private boolean success; //true if the WS call went ok, false otherwise
        private String errorMessage; //Error message to display if the WS call failed.
        private Object result; //Result, only if the WS  call succeeded.
        private boolean completed = false;

        //TODO getter and setters methods here
    }
```

In your screen, you can create an instance of result and wait for it:

```
    WSResult result = new WSResult();

    //Start thread here
    new Thread(new LoadCustomersTask(result)).start();

    //This is old school thread sync. 
    synchronized(result){
        while(!result.isCompleted()){
            result.wait();
        }
    }

    //Here the thread has returned, and we can diaplay the error message if any
    if(result.isSuccess()){

    } else {
        //Display result.getErrorMessage()
    }
```

Then your runnable would be like this:

```
    class LoadCustomersTask implements Runnable {
        private final WSResult result;
        public LoadCustomersTask(WSResult res){
            result = res;
        }

        public void run(){

            //Do the WS call

            //If it went well
            result.setSuccess(true);
            result.setResult(jsonResultados);

            //Else
            result.setSuccess(false);
            result.setErrorMessage("Your error message");


            //In any case, mark as completed
            result.setcompleted(true);

            //And notify awaiting threads           
            synchronized(result){
                result.notifyAll();
            }       
        }
    }
```

You can also do it with thread.join, but wait/notify is better because you not making the screen depend on the particular thread where the runnable runs. You can wait/notify on the result instance, as shown, or on the runnable if it is intended for a single use.

Question #4: Yes threads must not be abused, specially in JavaME where programs usually run in single core CPUs with a frecuency in the order of MHz. Try not to have more than 1-3 threads running at the same time. If you really need to, consider using a single thread for running all background tasks (a blocking queue).

Comment: Please,could you explain to me these lines : `synchronized(result)` and `result.wait()`;

Comment: In my answer I'm using `Object.wait/Object.notify` instead of `Thread.sleep/Thread.interrupt` to coordinate the threads. You can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1036754) for more info about the differences, but the idea is the same: one thread waits until the second thread is done. The synchronized block is needed whenever you call wait/notify, otherwise an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mister Smith I did as you suggested and now I have a much more organized code.