# Sleep but Release lock

Tags: java

I want to write a code block where I want my thread to sleep for say 10 minutes. I can do it via `Thread.sleep()`.

But, I want to release the acquired lock. So other thread can use it. I may use `object.wait()` in this situation. But I can't as other thread that acquire lock does `notify()` after processing. So my thread is woke up again may be prior to 10 minutes.

**What I need is exact sleep of 10 minutes and Also, I do not want to hold lock. So that other threads may use it.**

Please assist. Thanks

Comment: release the lock / sleep / reacquire the lock?

Comment: reacquire lock only after sleep of anticipated time (say 10 min). If any other thread calls notify then also I do not want sleeping thread to wake prior 10min expiration.

Comment: Basically I wan't to wait and release the lock. But wake up ony after expiration of sleep time no matters if other threads call notify.

Comment: Why don't you simply release the lock before sleeping like I suggested?

Comment: Sleep outside of the synchronized block. Then open a new synchronized block (re-acquire lock).

Comment: Use  `notify` --> `Thread#Sleep()` --> Sleep Completed --> `Reaquire lock`

Comment: and Read this [Difference between wait() and sleep()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1036763/3143670)

Comment: @assylias - Thanks got your point. Just one thing which is better, I mean another way can be to call while(true){ if(!condition) {obj.wait()}}.. or simply  like you put it sync(obj){} sleep() sync(obj){}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduler.schedule(runnableTask, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

where `runnableTask` is an instance of a class that implements `Runnable` and has the code you want to run in its `run()` method.

If you need that your code returns a value, use a `Callable` instead of a `Runnable`.

You might want to use a `synchronized` block with a lock in your code or any other concurrency construction to avoid that more than one thread runs your code concurrently.