# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working with `Thread` in  `Java` and i get following error - I don't understand why?!

Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     Vlakno sude = new Vlakno("myName"); // Vlakno = thread class

        sude.start();
        sude.wait(); // ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
    }

}

class Vlakno extends Thread {

    private boolean canIRun = true;
    private final String name;

    Vlakno(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (canIRun) {
          //  System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        }
    }

    public void mojeStop() {
        System.out.println("Thread "+name +" end...");
        this.canIRun = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to deal with the `IllegalMonitorStateException`, you must verify that all invocations of the wait method are taking place only when the calling thread owns the appropriate monitor. The most simple solution is to enclose these calls inside `synchronized` blocks. The synchronization object that shall be invoked in the `synchronized` statement is the one whose monitor must be acquired.

```
synchronize (sude) {
  sude.wait();
}
```

For more information and examples, take a look [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-illegalmonitorstateexception-how-to-solve-illegalmonitorstateexception/).

Answer (score 0):

From the Java Docs of `Object.wait`

> IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner
>   of the object's monitor.

After the invocation `sude.start();` you have two threads running: The current thread and the thread running `sude`. The current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.

To ensure that you are the owner of the object's monitor do this:

```
synchronize (sude) {
  sude.wait();
}
```