# Java Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner

Tags: java, multithreading, try-catch, wait

I am trying to make a wait in java using Thread, but i get the error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner`

I have tried

```java
Thread t = new Thread();
try {
    t.wait(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but It didn't work, I've searched StackOverFlow for answers but I couldn't find anything useful

Comment: Did you try the solution provided here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30262285/20325571 ?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? 1: make the current thread stop for a given time, that is,  `Thread.sleep(2000)`; or 2: wait for `t` to terminate, that would be `t.join(2000)` (but `t` was not even started...); or 3: really wait until `t.notify()` is called, then you need to move the `wait()` call inside a `synchronized (t)` block (not the best practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait` is a low-level construct designed to wait until something happens, and that something is *not* primarily 'x amount of time has passed'. It's for some *other* thread to signal: This is the moment.. wake up!

If you just want the thread to wait for a provided amount of time, the call you are looking for is not `t.wait`, but is `Thread.sleep(1000)` - that sleeps for 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

`wait` goes together with `notify`/`notifyAll` (those 2 methods do almost the same thing). One thread waits, another thread calls notify which causes the first thread to wake up. Yes, there is an overloaded variant of `wait` that takes an amount of milliseconds; that variant will wait until EITHER the stated amount of time has passed OR notify is called; whichever one occurs earlier.

To use wait/notify you need an object (and *all* objects can do this; in retrospect that wasn't a great way to design this part of the java language but it is what it is; changing it now would be quite backwards incompatible) - you need an object because different parts of your code can choose to do this wait/notify thing at the same time and it wouldn't do if they are all confused about who is signalling whom.

In addition, this notion of 'I wait until you tell me to resume' tends to run into some pretty severe threading errors very quickly, so in practice and because such a signal needs some sort of CPU gating anyway, java **requires** that you own the monitor on that object before you wait OR notify on it. Combining it all, this is what that looks like:

```
public class TrainStationPlatform {
  private final Object lock = new Object();
  private Train atPlatform = null;

  public void enterStation(Train train) {
    synchronized (lock) {
      while (atPlatform != null) {
        // Oh no! There's a train already at the platform!
        lock.wait(); // let's wait for it to leave.
      }

      // The platform is clear, we can enter!
      atPlatform = train;
    }
  }

  public void leave() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      if (atPlatform == null) throw new IllegalStateException("No train");
      atPlatform = null;
      lock.notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

This shows how you can use this:

- The above code is 'safe': It is not possible when using this code for 2 trains to be at the platform at the same time. Assume to understand this code each train is its own thread and calls `enter(this)` and `leave()` on its own. Any train trying to enter when there's a different train already at the platform will 'freeze' (its `enter` call will pause until the already-there train takes off, and *then* it will enter the platform, and the `enter` method returns).
- You can't call `x.notify` or `x.wait` unless you are inside a `synchronized (x)` block, where all `x`-es are referring to the same object.
- As an aside, locking on publically visible things is a very bad idea (maybe other code also locks on it, and then your code is a buggy mess-o-spaghetti nobody can understand or properly test!). threads are VERY public, and in fact, threads lock on themselves all the time, so using them as a lock object is horrible.
- Combine the above two rules, and you can correctly conclude that calling `t.wait()` where `t` is a thread is **never a correct action. Do not do this.**
- It shows *why* that locking (`synchronized`) is needed. Imagine the synchronized stuff wasn't there - you would draw the conclusion there is a train and in between drawing that conclusion and calling wait(), let's say the other thread makes the train that is there go away. You're still calling wait, waiting for an event that will never happen (because the train already left). This is the kind of crazy trickery that this construction avoids entirely by *requiring* that you lock on the think you want to call wait on first. The above code can never run into that problem.
- When you invoke `x.wait()`, your lock on `x` (the `synchronized` block, freezing all other threads that want to enter such a synchronized construct) is **relinquished** - other threads can now enter.
- When your `wait` call returns (whether by timeout if you use that, or because someone called notify), your thread does not **immediately** continue. After all, calling notify requires having the lock, and wait() won't continue until it has re-acquired it, which means it has to wait for whatever called notify to get to the end of its synchronized block first.
- `notify()` wakes up a random `wait()`ing thread, `notifyAll()` wakes them all up. It tends to be more sensible to perform the check to confirm whatever you need is there (or not there and requires `wait()`ing for) in a loop, and use `notifyAll()`. Easier to reason about, and there is no meaningful performance difference.
- These are fairly low-level; often there's something in the `java.util.concurrent` package that is easier to use and makes more sense for whatever inter-thread signalling needs you have.
- If you have no need to signal/gate between threads, do not use this stuff. Use `Thread.sleep` instead.
- Whatever object you use as a lock should virtually always be `private` - you want to keep very careful track of who uses it as a lock, which you can't do if code outside of your direct control can see that object. **If** you make it public, you either add extensive documentation explaining precisely what any code that acquires this object can and cannot do and how it is supposed to use it, **or** your code is a buggy mess that is going to result, sooner rather than later, in very nasty intermittent heisenbugs that take months to fix or end up being unfixable. So, don't.
- The exception `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner` occurs when you invoke `x.wait` or `x.notify/notifyAll` when you are *not* in a `synchronized (x)` block.
- If you want your objects to be serializable, use `private Object lock = new Object[0]`. arrays are serializable; `new Object()` is not, and `new Object[0]` is as light weight as they come.

Answer (score -1):

The thread that you have created, has never been started. I think you should so something like this:

```java
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.wait(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
});

t.start();
```

Comment: Try it - it results in the same exception. Answer not salvagable.