# Confusion between sleep() and wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, wait

These are a few conceptual doubts.

I read this in a book while preparing for SCJP

```
Just because a thread’s sleep() expires, and it wakes up, does not mean
it will return to running. It simply goes back to the runnable state.
So you can't rely on sleep() for an accurate timer.
```

Say I have threads `t1` and `t2` and an object `obj1`.

1) I have called `sleep()` for 5 seconds on `t1` which was doing some work on `obj1`. There is still some work pending to do by `t1` on `obj1`. `sleep()` does not release the lock on `obj1`. At the same time `t2` is trying to access `obj1`.

But if there is no guarantee that `t1` will get running again, could such a situation arise where `t2` would keep on waiting forever? Could such a situation be avoided?

2) If `t1` is making changes to `obj1` according to its task, and in between I call `wait()` on `t1`. `t2` steps in and makes changes to `obj1` according to its work.

When `t1` gets running again, it would be a mess, right? Because the state of `obj1` then would be whatever was done by `t2`, and `t1` would lose all the work done by it before `wait()` was called.

3) `wait()` is a non-static method, so could one thread cause another thread to wait, if it has a reference of the other thread? Is there any example to understand this kind of application?

4) Also I read something that `wait()` has to be called from a synchronized context, and it's a bad idea to call `sleep()` from a synchronized context. What is the reason for both of these?

Comment: I think your question is already answered :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep

Comment: I already saw that question, it did clear some of my doubts but not all.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between wait and sleep in Java :

1. wait release lock on object while waiting while sleep doesn't release lock while waiting.
2. wait is normally done on condition, Thread wait until a condition is true while sleep is just to put your thread on sleep.
3. wait is called from synchronized context only while sleep can be called without synchronized block. see Why wait and notify needs to call from synchronized method for more detail.
4. wait is called on Object while sleep is called on Thread. see Why wait and notify are defined in object class instead of Thread.
5. waiting thread can be awake by calling notify and notifyAll while sleeping thread can not be awaken by calling notify method.

Comment: All true, but you didn't say how either one of them was meant to be used.  `Thread.sleep()` is meant for timing.  It is the primitive operation that underlies `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and any other higher-level facility that makes things happen at specified times.  `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()` are meant for communication between threads.  They are the lowest-level mechanism that one thread can use to tell another, "I have done the thing that you are waiting for."

Answer (score 1):

Alright I'm going to try to answer this.

1. If `t1` **never** gets to run again, I'd say the kernel's thread scheduler is broken. I don't know where you got your idea that it would never run again.
2. If you have two threads making changes to one object, you need to make sure they behave properly. Such as using `synchronized` to make sure only one thread manipulates the object at a time. Your example is odd, because you seem to imply that the programmer doesn't decide what happens with the code.
3. You don't understand `wait()` and `notify()`. Search for a question about them, there's plenty.
4. `wait()` needs to be in synchronized context to get the object monitor. `sleep()` in synchronized context just creates an unnecessary block for other threads wanting to enter.

Comment: The first question was just a doubt of a possibility. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @vicky96 - It is *discouraged* to use `sleep()` for *timing things* because the *interrupt might happen correctly* but the scheduler might not *schedule* the execution of the thread immediately. A sleeping thread will not be scheduled until the time elapses.