# Getting unexpected results applying strace to a multithreaded Java process

Tags: java, multithreading, strace

I need to `strace` a multithreaded Java process that seems to have frozen. Following [this advice](https://meenakshi02.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/strace-hanging-at-futex/), I ran `ps -efL|grep <Process Name>` to get all the threads. However, when I then ran `strace -fp <thread_pid> -s 2000` I again got a bunch of lines like this:

```
[pid  2521] futex(0x7f91c4003c94, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  2520] futex(0x7f91ac003c94, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL <unfinished ...>
...
```

where `2521`, `2520`, etc are PIDs of all the threads, not just the one I tried to `strace`. Ultimately, I am trying to determine what's wrong with the job, and it seems that to find that out, I need detailed info on what the threads are doing. How do I get that?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of the applicacion?

Comment: Use `jconsole` or `jvisualvm` to attach to the process directly. Java runs in a Virtual Machine - you _will_ get odd results from trying to monitor it directly.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks. The machine I am running this on does not have `jvisualvm` installed. It does have `jconsole` but both tools are GUI-based and I only have a text-only connection to the machine. Are there any tools that are not GUI-based?

Comment: What do you mean by "text based"? SSH? Just use X forwarding...

Comment: Yes, SSH. I'll try forwarding

Comment: Otherwise you can use `kill -3` or `jstack` as described [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/generating-a-thread-dump-externally-182158040.html).

Comment: jconsole and jvisualvm allow remote connections, you just have to enable JMX in your java process.

Comment: See this answer about debugging the Java process.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093471/object-wait-exceeds-timeout/34094144#34094144