# Advantages and disadvantages using wait(1) over Thread.sleep(1)

Tags: java

As the question says is there any advantages or disadvantages for this:

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    try {
        monitor.wait(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Instead of using this:

```
Thread.sleep(1);
```

Comment: Those two methods are completely unrelated, do completely different things. Please explain what advantages or disadvantages you're talking about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in terms of PC performance so CPU usage