# Does "Thread.sleep()" do anything else than pause the program for a certain amount of time?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a program that draws a thick line.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Movement {
    int xGrid = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Movement m = new Movement();
        m.animate();
    }

    public void animate() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Movement");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ScreenDisplay display = new ScreenDisplay();

        frame.getContentPane().add(display);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int aL = 0; aL < 200; aL++) {

            xGrid++;

            display.repaint();

            try {

                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }

    class ScreenDisplay extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(xGrid, 175, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Because of the method "Thread.sleep(50)", the speed of the program slows down a little.

So I got a little curious and removed the "sleep()" method.

What I expected to output was the exact same output, just extremely fast.

However, it just prints out one circle in the frame.

I don't really know why it outputs just one circle, none of the researches I've done back up the answer.

Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: In the second example, the requests for repainting are queued, and you end up only seeing the result of the last one. With the `sleep`, you actually see the several repaints occuring .

Comment: You never call `super.paintComponent` in `ScreenDisplay`. That's going to make the graphics behave unpredictably.

Comment: Ahh, okay, thx for the answer, it really helped me tremendously! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between wait() and sleep()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep)

Comment: Thread.sleep() does not pause the _program_, it pauses the one thread within the program that called it.  Other threads continue to run.  If the program's threads are not well _synchronized_, then adding a sleep(), removing a sleep(), or changing the length of a sleep() potentially could alter the behavior and the correctness of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Component.repaint` documentation:

> Repaints this component.
>
> If this component is a lightweight component, this method
>         causes a call to this component's `paint`
>         method as soon as possible.  Otherwise, this method causes
>         a call to this component's `update` method as soon
>         as possible.

By the looks of it, your for loop finishes so quickly that by the time the component calls the `repaint` method, it has already finished and therefore only paints the final circle stored in the buffer.