# Get output of a running bash script with java

Tags: java, processbuilder

Normally I use this code to run a bash script and get it's output

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/myscript");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String inputRead;
p.waitFor();
while((inputRead=stdInput.readLine()) != null){
    Helper.log(inputRead);
}
```

This works fine but this time the bash script I am using didn't terminate. It's always active and when it detect something it print it. I want to start the script, wait for some time and than check if it detected something. I tried to use `p.wait(periode);`
I tried this code

```
p.wait(10000);
while((inputRead=stdInput.readLine()) != null){
    Helper.log(inputRead);
}
```

I am not sure if it's the right solution for my problem but anyway I get an error with this code

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

My question is not really about waiting, but how to stop the process after waiting and still be able to get the output.

Comment: Usually, IllegalMonitorStateException means that a thread is trying to wait/notify an object monitor without owning it. Make sure no threads are trying to do that.

Comment: I see what you're doing. p.wait() needs to be inside a synchronized statement: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html. If you want the thread to wait, use Thread.sleep().

Comment: The script "/home/myscript" write to a file?

Comment: What makes you think that calling `Object.wait()` on the `Process` object is a good idea? It's not - that method has a totally different purpose, and has the precondition that you need to hold the monitor on the object (synchronize on it). But that's not the fix for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete example of the solution. A separate thread switches a flag for the main thread to terminate and then output the collected lines:

```
private static boolean triggerToClose = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
      InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder pb =
        new ProcessBuilder("/home/myscript");
    Process p = pb.start();
    java.io.InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String inputRead;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        triggerToClose = true;
      }
    }).start();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputRead = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
      if (triggerToClose) {
        p.destroy();
        break;
      }

      sb.append(inputRead).append('\n');
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
  }
```

Comment: This might also help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep

Comment: If i use this command the threat will never terminate. If i use p.destroy(); after your code I will not be able to get the output result, I got the message java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: The sleep() command shouldn't keep the current thread running for more than the time specified as an argument. Are you sure that the process started by /home/myscript really terminates?

Comment: No the process  /home/myscript  never terminate this is the problem. I just want to run the script for a short period of time, in this example 10 seconds  then stop it and get the output generated by the script in this period.

Comment: The answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

In your case using .wait(1000), is totally wrong. That's what the exception also tells you.
Exactly for your usecase there's `waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`:

```
p.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thank you but I used your code and the threat never terminated. Maybe I should destroy the process after this code ? But as I said, if I destroy it I am not able to get the output anymore

Comment: Did you remove the while loop after using my proposal?

Comment: No but the while loop is just for logging the input generated from the script. And the script never stops because I still have the input logged for ever