# Can't have 2 threads running at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a superclass called GameThread:

```
public class GameThread implements Runnable {
public static Thread thread;
public static boolean running = false;
public static double fps = 1;
public static double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;

public static ArrayList<GameThread> gameThreads = new ArrayList<>();

public void run(){
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = 0;

    while(running){
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
        timer += now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;

        setFps();

        if(delta >= 1){
            action();
            delta--;
        }

        if(timer >= 1000000000){
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void start(){
    if (running) return;
    running = true;
    startThread();
    thread.start();
}

public void action(){}
public void setFps(){}
public void startThread(){}
```

And 2 threads which are children of GameThread:

```
public class JumpThread extends GameThread {
public JumpThread(){
    start();
}

@Override
public void action(){
    //code
}

@Override
public void setFps(){
    //code
}

@Override
public void startThread(){
    thread = new Thread(new JumpThread());
}
```

and

```
public class HydroponicsThread extends GameThread {
public HydroponicsThread(){
    start();
}

@Override
public void action(){
    //code
}

@Override
public void setFps(){
    //code
}

@Override
public void startThread(){
    thread = new Thread(new HydroponicsThread());
}
```

My problem is, when I initialize them:

```
GameThread.gameThreads.add(new HydroponicsThread());
GameThread.gameThreads.add(new JumpThread());
```

Only the first one (HydroponicsThread) works, the "run()" method on the other won't be called. 
My guess is the while loop is stopping the JumpThread from being initialized, but I can't find a way to do this without it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code starts no threads and fails with a `StackOverflowError`. `JumpThread` constructor -> `start()` -> `startThread()` -> `JumpThread` constructor.

Comment: The first one works just fine. If I change their order the other one will work.

Comment: Ah yes, you prevent it with the flag. However... still quite bad code.

Comment: I am aware its bad code. I started trying to teach myself to code a few months ago

Comment: Another obvious fail: `public static Thread thread;` You use a static variable from instance context.

Comment: And `running` is also static, which trivially explains why only your first thread starts. It changes the flag to true once, and then it's true for all instances. If you make it non-static, then you'll get the stack overflow I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake, in the start() method:

```
public synchronized void start(){
    if (running) return;
    running = true;
    //startThread(); (mistake)
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
```

Also, I removed the start() method from the threads' constructor

Comment: Good fix. Instead of `running` flag you can simply use the check `thread != null`.

Comment: No, but eliminating redundancy is always a good thing. However, the `running` flag is useful when you need to signal a long-running task that you want it to end.

Comment: In fact you can retain just the `running` flag. You never use the `thread` variable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid "hugging" the cpu you should introduce some pause in the action of your run method, either using *sleep* or *wait*.

Check [Difference between wait() and sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep) for a discussion of your options.