# Tweaking HSQL: How can I reduce CPU power needed

Tags: hsqldb

I have an application, using the HSQL database, that at very rare ocassions needs to copy a lot of data (5 million rows+) into the database. On an i7 this takes about 3 hours which is perfectly fine.

The issue I have is that on a weaker CPU like an i3 it is not possible to do this copy task at all since the CPU usage is at 100% at all cores and as a consequence the whole application freezes.

I'm looking for a solution to "throttle" the data entering process. It's totally okay if the copy process takes much longer as long as it completes and doesn't freeze the application.

I have been looking through the official documentation here: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html but couldn't find what I was looking for.

What would be the best approach to get this task working also on weaker CPUs?

Comment: The common approach is to add a pause to your Java program after every 10 rows inserted. Thread.sleep() perhaps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep

Comment: I have tried to add a sleep of 5 seconds after each 100 rows which gained me an average of 10% cpu cycle time. I guess this is the only suitable approach then!

Comment: Actual CPU usage should be a lot less if it is working for 1s or less then waiting for 5s. Look at total CPU time report for the process and see if it is reported correctly.

Comment: I have measured it with windows process explorer. The thing is I have 50 threads (Each with their own dataabse connection) and each needs to enter about 100.000 rows at the same time into different tables. As I said I tell each thread to sleep for 5 seconds after entering 100 rows and I only see at maximum a 10% improvement.

Comment: This is the slow way to populate the database. Use one thread to populate table by table and it will be much faster overall and use much less CPU.

Comment: I'm fully aware of this. The problem is that there is no single data source I get my data from. I get my data from 50 different physical industrial machines and a top requirement is that the update of one machine does not block the update from another machine. I'd love to only have a single thread to do the work. AS a fact I already implemented such a solution but it got rejected since the update of one machine blocks the update of all other machines until its done :/
Thanks for your input anyway, maybe I can make something more clever ;)