# synchronised block and synchronised methods of the same instance

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a bit confused about `synchronized`-blocks in Java.

If one thread enters a `synchronized`-block of an instance of a class, can other threads use `synchronized`-methods of the same instance of the same class?

```
void myMain() {
    synchronized(this) {
        while(suspendFlag)
             wait();
        }
    }
}

synchronized void mysuspend() {
    suspendFlag = true;
}
```

Comment: yes they can. Synchronized method and synchronized statements are functionally equivalent.

Comment: The answer is no, because both `synchronized` area from your code lock on the instance itself. Thus other threads can't access it while current thread is executing in any of the 2 `synchronized` area. But, the current thread itself can, that's called `re-entrant`.

Answer (score 1):

```
synchronized void mysuspend(){
    suspendFlag = true;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
void mysuspend(){
    synchronized(this) {
        suspendFlag = true;
    }
}
```

So in your code it is not possible that one thread enters a `synchronized` block of an instance of a class and other threads use synchronized method `mysuspend()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because they are independently callable.
A thread is not attached to a class or an instance of it. Each method of a class may be called independently from different threads.

What can limit this independence are `synchronized` methods. They are shortcuts for `synchronized(this) {...}` as method body.

Whenever a `synchronized` block is entered, the monitor on the associated instance is held.

A `wait()` frees the monitor on the surrounding `synchronized` block again, so other synchronized blocks can be executed.

There is a problem with your code: `wait()` will wait until a `notify()` on the monitor is called. But in your code neither a `notify()` is called, nor has the `wait()` a timeout.

Your `while(suspendFlag) wait();` will then wait forever...

Comment: I did not copy the whole file. Before the synchronized block, Thread.sleep(200); is added. It is used by one thread. And mysuspend() is used by the main thread. And this method is preceded by Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: `sleep()` does not end a `wait()`. Only `notify()` or `wait(timeout)` after the timeout will.
You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep which explains some things..

Comment: @neo360, Don't try to _describe_ your code, and especially, don't try to describe it in a comment. If there's something you haven't already shown that would better explain your question, then edit the question, and add the actual code.